# Squishing docker image without spinning a container

Tags: docker

I am using docker to analyse changes to the file system caused by various commands. I simply add relevant `RUN` lines in the `Dockerfile`, build it, use `docker save` to see what changes were made. Unfortunately I use many commands, end even though most of the time I can put several of them into one layer, I usually exceed the rather low 127 parent layers limit.

To deal with this I squish images with many layers into images with just one layer, and use the resulting image as the parent for the rest of the new layers. The best way to do that is to spin up a container and then use `docker export`, and then to `docker import` that to get a nice single layer of changes. I am looking for ways to shave down the time it takes to perform that operation.

Is there a simple way to do the same thing (export the fully expanded file system of an image, not just the layers stack as in `docker save`) without spinning up a container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No matter what the method, squashing a complete container is always going to be a process of reading the layered file system and writing a new flat file system, which involves io, which is relatively slow.

Creating a container is extremely light weight in comparison so I'm not sure you will gain much by getting rid of that step

```
time container=$(docker create debian)
time docker export $container | docker import -  debian_flat
time docker rm $container
```

On an ssd based system, results in:

Create

```
real    0m0.050s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.010s
```

Export/Import

```
real    0m8.213s
user    0m2.867s
sys     0m0.768s
```

Remove

```
real    0m0.019s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.008s
```

There are other tools that let [you squash selected layers](https://github.com/goldmann/docker-squash#squashing). This may save you time as you only need to read and write a portion of the data. If your requirement is the squashing the complete image then I'm not sure this will be much quicker than an export/import as you are still reading and writing the same amount of data.

There's a [github issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/332) to cover the squash feature in official docker and [pull requests](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/8600) for [support](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/13929) to directly squash or flatten layers in docker and builds. Each request seems to slowly die off before being accepted though.